# Create an alias of relation in select_related in Django

Tags: django, alias, relation, django-select-related

i have the model:

```
Rubric(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Rubric has seo parameters

```
class RubricSeo(models.Model):
    rubric = models.OneToOneField(Rubric)
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

To select the rubric with seo i have to use:

```
rubric = Rubric.objects.select_related('rubricseo',).get(id=rubric_id)
```

And then use in template:

```
{{ rubric.rubricseo.title}}
```

But i need to create an alias to this relation `rubricseo` (i mean `LEFT JOIN rubricseo as seo...`), and then use `{{ rubric.seo.title}}`. But i cant rename the model to simple `Seo`.

Is it possible to do? Does `select_related` allow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the relation like that:

```
rubric = models.OneToOneField(Rubric, related_name='seo')
```

Then you can access the related model via:

```
{{ rubric.seo.title}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `related_name` in the definition of your Model.

```
class RubricSeo(models.Model):
    rubric = models.OneToOneField(Rubric, related_name='seo')
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

You still need to use `select_related`

```
rubric = Rubric.objects.select_related('seo').get(id=rubric_id)
```